# django/postgresql current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

I was getting the above error, when I was submitting a model form, I tried -

1.

```
from django.db import transaction
transaction.rollback()
```

2

```
from django import db
from django.db.backends.util import CursorDebugWrapper
old_execute = CursorDebugWrapper.execute
old_execute_many = CursorDebugWrapper.executemany

def execute_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    try:
        old_execute(*args, **kwargs)
    except Exception, ex:
        logger.error("Database error:\n%s" % ex)
        db.close_connection

def excecute_many_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    try:
        old_execute_many(*args, **kwargs)
    except Exception, ex:
        logger.error("Database error:\n%s" % ex)
        db.close_connection

CursorDebugWrapper.execute = execute_wrapper
CursorDebugWrapper.executemany = excecute_many_wrapper
```

3

```
from django.db import connection
connection._rollback()
```

4

```
manage.py migrate
```

or

```
manage.py syncdb
```

**and then resubmitted the model form, nothing again seemed to happen.**

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you share the model and form in question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to display postgresql log to find out what's the problem, there's a wrong SQL query.

```
tail -f /var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_log/postgresql-Thu.log
```